# Remove all tags before store tags

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, tags, relationship

I have this code

```
  private function hashtagName($string){
    $name = $string;
    $name = ltrim($name, '#');
    $name = trim($name);
    return $name;
  }
  private function hashtags($article){
    $htag = '#';
    $arr = explode(" ", $article->description);
    $arrc = count($arr);
    $i = 0;
    $arr_id = [];
    while($i < $arrc){
      if(substr($arr[$i], 0, 1) === $htag ){
        $hash = Hashtag::firstOrCreate(
            ['name' => $this->hashtagName($arr[$i]), 'slug' => str_slug(ltrim($arr[$i], '#'))]
        );

        if (! $article->hashtags->contains('hashtag_id', $this->hashtagName($arr[$i]))) {
          $article->hashtags()->save($hash);
        }
      }
      $i++;
    }
  }
```

This code store tags into db correctly. I have a problem if I try use a few  hashtags in WYSCIWYG editor. Very often WYSCIWYG editor add it's own html tags and this code save it. For example it stored in DB helloworld